# Kotlin Gradle: add "compile ..."

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dependency-management

I have an almost brand new Gradle based project:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
    application
}

group = "me.arekbulski"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

How do I add the following? Where do I put it?

```
compile ‘org.bitbucket.akornilov.kotlin:binary-streams:0.1’
```

I found it here:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/i-o-streams-for-kotlin/9802

Comment: Try `implementation("org.bitbucket.akornilov.kotlin:binary-streams:0.1")` (in the `dependencies` block).

Comment: It works, thanks!